How to make sure mockwebserver is started before running test?
How do I ensure that mock web server is started before test runs ?
MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
            server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200));
    server.start(8888);

// run application logic that sends http request

                RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                server.shutdown();

But sometimes my test fails. because there is no server started. But if I add sleep, it works.
    MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
                server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                        .setResponseCode(200));
        server.start(8888);
        Thread.sleep(1500);


You would need build your own test rule and ensure the order is before other rules that launching the app. For example, AndroidComposeTestRule. I just did it today and worked for me.

Sorry for naive question but what do you mean by rule ? How do I check server is up  before starting test ?

It is not clear what platform you are workign on. You might have to post compelte code. In my case I am working for Android..

Its Java + Spring Boot app. Junit and mockito for testing
